sed to replace a value in xml
Below is an excerpt of an xml file I need to modify:
<config>
    <panel>
        <name>AppsPanel</name>
        <visible>false</visible
    </panel>
    <panel>
        <name>FilesPanel</name>
        <masked>false</masked>
    </panel><panel>
        <name>MarketPanel</name>
        <masked>false</masked>

I need to replace the first instance of "false" with "true".
Note that the <visible> key only appears on this one line.  All of the other keys with a true/false value have different names.
The output should look like:
<config>
    <panel>
        <name>AppsPanel</name>
        <visible>true</visible
    </panel>
    <panel>
        <name>FilesPanel</name>
        <masked>false</masked>
    </panel><panel>
        <name>MarketPanel</name>
        <masked>false</masked>

I'm deploying this remotely to a bunch of macOS computers with varying OS versions macOS 12 - macOS 15). Installing other tools isn't an option.
My script:
ServiceConfigFile="/path/to/ServiceConfig.xml"
if [ -f "$ServiceConfigFile" ]; then
    serviceconfpresent="true"
    echo "serviceconfig.xml exists"
    sed -i '' 's/<visible>false</visible>/<visible>true</visible/g' "$ServiceConfigFile"

else
    serviceconfpresent="false"
    echo "serviceconfig.xml does not exist."
fi

Results in the error
sed: 1: "s/<visible>false</visib ...": bad flag in substitute command: '<' 
I'm assuming this is due to the "/" in the <visible> tag, so I modified sed to this:
sed -i '' 's/<visible>false<\/visible>/<visible>true<\/visible/g' "$ServiceConfigFile"
No errors are generated, but the file is not updating.
So far my googlefu has let me down.
Any pointers?

Regular expressions are the wrong tool to use with xml. You need something xpath based, like xmlstarlet

Use XML tools to work with XML  This particular job would be pretty easy for an XSLT processor.

If sed and XML appear in the same sentence, then something is already wrong.

If this is a .plist file, you can use defaults write to update it.

With valid XML: xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl --update '//visible' -v "true" file.xml

while the answers (see referenced Q&A duplicate) will work they are overkill for this particular case; in this case all you need to do is change sed's default script delimiter (/) to something you know won't show up the data (eg, |): sed 's|<visible>false</visible>|<visible>true</visible>|g' cfg.xml; fwiw, was in the middle of writing up that answer when the question was closed

?? I'm assuming the sample input contains a typo on your behalf and that in your actual xml file the line <visible>true</visible actually contains a trailing >; I'm assuming this is related to your code's sed call which makes the mistake of leaving off the trailing >

Ok, so my searching did not come across the similar questions.  I'll try harder next time.
